# Help converting string based array to class variable name

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an array, which are the literal names of class references.  Eg. in my main class I have

```
var page1:PageOne =   new PageOne();
var page2:PageTwo =   new PageTwo();
var page3:PageThree = new PageThree();

var sectionsArray = new Array ('page1', 'page2', 'page3')
```

What I'd like to write, but can't is:

```
var sectionsArray = new Array (page1, page2, page3)
```

I am trying to tween something based on these values, but since the value is of type String, I cannot associate these values with the class references they represent. So I tried something like:

```
var tweenObj:Object = _sectionsArray[0] as Object
TweenLite.to(tweenObj, 1, {alpha:0});
```

But all this does is make it an Object of type String (and throw a tweenLite error because i tried to tween a string), which does not help me.

What is a better way to think about handling what I'm trying to do?

Thanks very much in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [] initiation instead. Not only will it work with what you are trying to achieve it's also faster than using new.

```
var sections:Array = [page1, page2, page3];
```

Then when using the object you simply do:

```
TweenLite.to(sections[0], 1, {alpha:0});
```

Since all the objects in the array already the right type you don't need to typecast them before using them with `Tweenlite`.

**Proof of concept:**

```
var page1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var page2:Sprite = new Sprite();
var page3:Sprite = new Sprite();

var sections:Array = [page1, page2, page3];

trace(sections[0]);
trace(sections[1]);
trace(sections[2]);
```

**Output:**

```
[object Sprite]
[object Sprite]
[object Sprite]
```

Comment: Edit your question and put your output and explain in more detail what kind of error you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had tried that before btw and the reason it failed for me is I was instantiating my page classes deep in the script in a switch, so it was tracing null. When I put page1:PageOne = new PageOne before the constructor it all worked. Thanks again!!